# Parse json with jq in aws cli

Tags: amazon-ec2, jq

i need an output similar to this

```
{
  "InstanceType": "c4.xlarge",
  "PrivateIpAddress": "10.54.130.52",
  "PlatformDetails": "Windows BYOL",
  "State":
    "Name": "running"
  }
}
```

Reading the documentation of the jq command I have reached the next output:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids i-0079e143722b0b8f9 | jq -r '.Reservations[].Instances[] | {InstanceType, PrivateIpAddress, PlatformDetails, State}'
{
  "InstanceType": "c4.xlarge",
  "PrivateIpAddress": "10.54.130.52",
  "PlatformDetails": "Windows BYOL",
  "State": {
    "Code": 16,
    "Name": "running"
  }
}
```

Can anyone explain how to do that?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
 aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids i-0079e143722b0b8f9 | jq -r '.Reservations[].Instances[] | {InstanceType, PrivateIpAddress, PlatformDetails, State: {Name:.State.Name} }'
```

Comment: Solved!! thanks man